# Insert post programmatically and decide to tweet or not to tweet

Tags: wp-insert-post, post-meta, twitter

I am inserting a new post using `wp_insert_post()` and want to be able to decide if this post gets tweeted or not using the `WP to Twitter` plugin.

**First**, I create the post, like so:

```
$newpost = array(
    'post_title' => 'Hello world',
    'post_content' => 'Is it a good day to tweet or not?',
    'post_status' => 'draft'
);
$newpostid = wp_insert_post($newpost);
```

**Second**, I update the postmeta table by setting:

```
if($tweet_this_post == true) {
    update_post_meta($newpostid, '_jd_tweet_this', 'yes');
}
else {
    update_post_meta($newpostid, '_jd_tweet_this', 'no');
}
```

Thus far, everything works as expected. The post gets created and the postmeta table gets set with the option `_jd_tweet_this` to be either `yes` or `no`. So far, so good.

However, since I set up the `WP to Twitter` to tweet all new posts by default, the postmeta table *always already contains* the `_jd_tweet_this` option set to `yes` by default. And I cannot override it by using the `update_post_meta()` function as described above.

When I set `$tweet_this_post` to `false`, I end up with two (2) entries for `_jd_tweet_this` in the postmeta table - the default `yes` has a lower meta_id value than the value inserted by my `update_post_meta()` function. Which indicates to me, that the default value (yes) was inserted **BEFORE** the programmatically added value (no), which suggests that the `update_post_meta()` function **IS NOT UPDATING** the existing value for `_jd_tweet_this`.

**My question:** Can anybody explain to me what I need to do to programmatically control if an inserted post in draft status gets tweeted when I manually publish it from the dashboard?

**Updated:** Here is the code, which is contained in my functions.php:

```
function wpcf7_to_post($cfdata) {
    $formtitle = $cfdata->title;
    if($formtitle == 'front-end-add-post') {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if($submission) {
            $formdata = $submission->get_posted_data();

            // insert new post with form data
            $newpost = array(
                'post_title' => trim($formdata['title']),
                'post_content' => trim($formdata['content']),
                'post_status' => 'draft',
                'post_type' => 'post'
            );
            $newpostid = wp_insert_post($newpost);

            // tweet this post?
            if(in_array('yes', $formdata['tweet'])) {
                update_post_meta($newpostid, '_jd_tweet_this', 'yes');
            }
            else {
                update_post_meta($newpostid, '_jd_tweet_this', 'no');
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_to_post', 1);
```

As you can see, I am using CF7 plugin for front page submission of new posts and I am reading the data from the form (this all works fine ;-))... Thanks!

Comment: `update_post_meta` updates an already existing meta field; it only creates new one row in the database if the field doesn't exist. Can you post the full code you are using?

Comment: Hi @cybmeta, thank you for your answer. Yes, update_post_meta will create a new entry if the meta does not exist in the postmeta table. The code above is basically the full code. Directly after creating the post (I read the input of a form submission), I update the post meta instantly thereafter...

Comment: You said that `update_post_meta` is inserting new row in the database instead of updating existing one, that is why we need to see the full code, otherwise we can not know if the problem is in your code or anywhere esle, for example in the plugin you are using (in this case you should contact with the developer as thrid party plugins are off-topic here). So, please, post the full code beacuse the information you have provided is not enough to answer the question, at least for me.

Comment: I've updated my question with a link to my code on pastebin ;-) Thank you!

Comment: Please, add the code in the question and not in a external source.

Comment: I've added the code inline. Sorry, I thought that adding the code on an external platform would help to keep SO free of cluttering code fragments... ;-)

Comment: In your code, I don't see anything that could be duplicating meta fields instead of updating them. You should contact with the developer of `WP to Twitter` plugin to ask him/her/them how the plugin creates the meta field. PD: This site is almost 100% about code, so there are not cluttering code fragments.